# Updating Datatable using Update Query

Tags: sql

I am passing string _nameProcessed from the UI to my DAL and updating my table. Now when I am doing the foreach look I could not figure if out how to Update my column ShipmentProcessedBy to _nameProcessed.

Any help guys???

```
 public void SaveNameProcessed(DataTable updatedTable, string _nameProcessed)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in updatedTable.Rows)
        {

            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(
                @"update dbo.JobStatus 
                    SET ShipmentProcessedBy = ????, 
                    WHERE JobTableId = @JobID ", _mySqlConnec);

            //Updated the parameters to the SQL Query!
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProcessedBy", row["ProcessedBy"].ToString()));
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@JobID", row["JobID"].ToString()));

            cmd2.Connection = _mySqlConnec;
            _mySqlConnec.Open();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _mySqlConnec.Close();
        }

    }
```

Here is the rectified code:

```
 public void SaveNameProcessed(DataTable updatedTable, string _nameProcessed)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in updatedTable.Rows)
        {

            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(
                @"update dbo.JobStatus 
                    SET ShipmentProcessedBy = ????, 
                    WHERE JobTableId = @JobID ", _mySqlConnec);

            //Updated the parameters to the SQL Query!
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProcessedBy", _nameProcessed));
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@JobID", row["JobID"].ToString()));

            cmd2.Connection = _mySqlConnec;
            _mySqlConnec.Open();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _mySqlConnec.Close();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared and added a parameter called `@ProcessedBy` so just set it to that in your SQL.

`SET ShipmentProcessedBy = @ProcessedBy,`

Exactly the same as you have done with `@JobId`

You also need to change this line:

`cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProcessedBy", row["ProcessedBy"].ToString()));`

to

`cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProcessedBy", _nameProcessed));`

Comment: I corrected the above code according to what you said. I still cannot figure it out, what should be in the update statement?

Comment: You still need to do what I have said.  Replace the ???? with the variable name @ProcessedBy